# How can I turn a set of edges into a curve?

Tags: edit-mode, bezier-curves, edges

I'm trying to make a curve from a set of angled edges, but I can't seem to find the right tool to do so.

Replicating this curve

[image]

Trying to turn selected Edges into a Curve

[image]

I tried using the LoopTools addon making a curve, but that didn't work. So is it possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do it another way:

- Create some loop cuts on each face (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>):

[image]

- Move up the top central edges with the *Proportional Editing* enabled:

[image]

- Extrude up and right click > *LoopTools > Circle*:

[image]

- Add some edge loops to rearrange the shape and sharpen some edges:

[image]

Comment: this seems to have solved the problem yes, thanks!